# error while pressuing multiple times physical back button of device in android

Tags: android

I am facing this error while I am pressing back multiple times on the physical button of device.

This is my log:

```
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98): Load: 4.16 / 3.77 / 2.21
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98): CPU usage from 141136ms to 62ms ago:
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   system_server: 8% = 6% user + 2% kernel / faults: 3797 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   dhd_dpc: 2% = 0% user + 2% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   om.htc.launcher: 1% = 1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1095 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   mediaserver: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1610 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   d.process.acore: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4617 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   e.pluginmanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 389 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   akmd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 69 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   adbd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 331 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   id.defcontainer: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 153 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   tc.RosieUtility: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 81 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   android.vending: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 61 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   com.htc.bg: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 47 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   e.process.gapps: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 62 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   com.htc.bgp: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 67 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   s:FriendService: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 47 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   equicksearchbox: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 45 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   wpa_supplicant: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   droid.apps.maps: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 50 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   com.svox.pico: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 40 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   suspend: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   cabc_work_q: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   panel_on/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 18 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   ksoftirqd/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   .android.htcime: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 45 minor 1 major
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   com.android.mms: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 13 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   get.clockwidget: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   atmel_wq: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   ls_wq/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   rild: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 31 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 10 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   com.htc.music: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   ogle.android.gm: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   com.fd.httpd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   d.apps.uploader: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   init: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   netd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   android.updater: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   roid.worldclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   c.android.Stock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   com.htc.fm: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   MessageUploader: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   ec.android.jbed: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   roid.footprints: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   android.browser: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):   tc.android.mail: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):  +flush-179:0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):  +om.amritbani.tv: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98):  +om.amritbani.tv: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-03 18:47:50.403: ERROR/ActivityManager(98): TOTAL: 24% = 14% user + 8% kernel + 0% softirq
```

Answer (score 0):

It is looked like that  this error occur because of the emulator. This is error of the emulator.
Create New Emulator and try your code again.